# JavaScript - how to directly call a function from .js file without providing it's reference

Tags: javascript, function, protractor

I would like to invoke function without providing the .js file name where this function is stored.

In helpers.js file have function like this (it's not the only function in this file) :

```
exports.clickOn = function (element) {
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element), waitTimeout).then(function () {
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), waitTimeout)
    }).then(function () {
        element.click();
    });
};

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var waitTimeout = 10000;
```

Function is called in spec.js file in following way:

```
var InitPage = require('../pages/init_page.js');
var LogInToSystem = require('../helper.methods/test_with_system_authentication');
var Helpers = require('../helper.methods/helpers.js');

describe('Test -> my test', function () {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var waitTimeout = 10000;
    var helper = Helpers;
    beforeEach(function () {
        LogInToSystem.AsAdmin();
        var initPage = new InitPage;
        helper.clickOn(initPage.usersButton);
    });
```

I would like to call `clickOn` function without `helper.` - just `clickOn(initPage.usersButton);` - in java I could just import static this exact method but js do not allows on it. Could anyone advise how ?

Comment: You can't do this.  Javascript is not Java. Javascript parses and compiles everything in the file. Why do you want to do this?  If you explain your motivation there may be another way

Comment: Why can't you include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is `protractor`-specific, you can make a function available globally using `global`:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    var helpers = require('../helper.methods/helpers.js');
    global.clickOn = helpers.clickOn;

    // ...
},
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is basically turning off namespaceing in RequireJS. Polluting the namespace is a bad idea. That's one of the reasons why AMD is a thing in JavaScript.

If you really want to pollute the namespace though, you can use this:

```
var helper = Helpers;
var clickOn = helper.clickOn;
beforeEach(function () {
    LogInToSystem.AsAdmin();
    var initPage = new InitPage;
    clickOn(initPage.usersButton);
});
```